# Array in loop PHP Looping through arrays with for loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Hi Can I use loop in array? can you help me about how to use?

```
    if($oran->typeid =="235")
        {
            foreach($oran->fields as $yoran)  
                {
        $tip = "Name";
        $say = count($yoran);       
            for($i=0; $i<$say; $i++) {
        $array73 = array(
            "tip" => $tip,
            "id" => 42,
            "values" => array(
                              "1"=>array("tur"=>"$yoran->desc","tid"=>"233","val"=>$yoran->value,
                              )));  
            }
        array_push($kod,$array73);
        }}
```

what i want...

```
>  for($i=0; $i<$say; $i++) {
>                                    
>      "1"=>array("tur"=>"$yoran->desc","tid"=>"233","val"=>$yoran->value,
>     )
>     
>       }
```

I am dynamically trying to populate a multidimensional array and having some trouble.

https://i.ibb.co/CKCrF3X/asd.jpg

Comment: A correct indentation helps a lot to visualise a code

Comment: You need to index the array, like so: `$yoran[$i]->value`. This is assuming it is an array with numerical keys.

Comment: how can i use loop in array

Comment: Is that what you're trying to do ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c5fb57922bd3c224ba2ba7122966e21c462943b4

Comment: @Jules R Thank you so much for your help. I'm sorry my English isn't very good. I've added photos, would you please review?   https://i.ibb.co/CKCrF3X/asd.jpg

Comment: Alright something like this ? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/35ffca0994e8b69b765fa00fec1cabad90dcb5ea Notice that `array[] = $val` is the same as `array_push($array, $val)`

Comment: Thank you very much, yes that's what I want, I'm grateful to you .

Comment: @MertFırat np, just remember to put in the loop what you want to appear several times and outside what should appear only once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't fully understand what you try to do,
but i believe that [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) will help you

Comment: what i want. -->  "1"=>array("tur"=>"$yoran->desc","tid"=>"233","val"=>$yoran->value,"  2 3 4 5 (array in array loop)

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR), expecting ')'